# building yaws rest api

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am trying to build REST based APIs using Erlang & YAWS. My code is in github https://gist.github.com/rgrajan/11204417, getting error

> record arg already defined

I am new to Erlang, the entire code is forked from user hiyosi, which is an erl file and compiles successfully. I am trying to convert the same to YAWS. The problem is i didn't get the line number for the error, so it's difficult to debug. Any way to get the line number is also useful.

Comment: The error is coming at `method(Arg) ->
    Rec = Arg#arg.req,
    Rec#http_request.method.`

Comment: The problem maybe in this `-include("../../include/yaws_api.hrl").`

Comment: Perfect. I just commented the above line and tried. It worked. Thought of updating the answer, but i saw your comments. Great @BlackMamba.

Comment: Could you detail how you got this to actually run and serve the REST API?